# Auto Layout for UIScrollView w/ 2 Child Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode6, autolayout

I have a scroll view that's set up inside a storyboard with auto layout constraints so that it fills the entire view. The scroll view contains two views managed by UIViewControllers instantiated from nibs. The code to include these subviews:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
ContentViewController *contentVC = [ContentViewController new];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContentView" owner:contentVC options:nil];

self.scrollView.delegate = self;
[self addChildViewController:contentVC];
[self.scrollView addSubview:contentVC.contentTC.view];
[contentVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:contentVC.contentTC];

self.view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.view.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
self.scrollView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
self.scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
CGRect adminFrame = contentVC.view.frame;
adminFrame.origin.x = adminFrame.size.width;

ShareViewController *shareViewController = [[ShareViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareView" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:shareViewController];
[self.scrollView addSubview:shareViewController.view];

shareViewController.view.frame = adminFrame;


CGRect shareFrame = shareViewController.view.frame;
shareFrame.origin.x = shareFrame.size.width;

[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:0]];


// 4) Finally set the size of the scroll view that contains the frames
CGFloat scrollWidth  = 2 * self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat scrollHeight  = self.view.frame.size.height;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Don't have the ability to post an image, but here's a link to what it looks like:

dropbox.com/s/e84ya3ffrdzytac/Screenshot%202015-08-19%2011.52.15.png

In the iphone 6+ simulator, the scrollview is smaller in both width and height than the window, so there's white space on the right and bottom.

In the iPhone 4S simulator, the width is correct, but the subviews are longer than the window, which means that they'll scroll down. This only works in the iPhone 5, even though all of the views are inferred and not set up for 4-inch screens.

Apologies if this is a redundant question, but I've been searching through SO and banging my head against the wall for two days now, help would be appreciated.

** EDIT: UPDATED CODE AND BEHAVIOR: **

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
ContentViewController *contentVC = [ContentViewController new];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContentView" owner:contentVC options:nil];

self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.scrollView addSubview:contentView];

[self addChildViewController:contentVC];
[contentView addSubview:contentVC.contentTC.view];
[contentVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:contentVC.contentTC];

CGRect adminFrame = contentVC.view.frame;
adminFrame.origin.x = adminFrame.size.width;


ShareViewController *shareViewController = [[ShareViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareView" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:shareViewController];
[contentView addSubview:shareViewController.view];

shareViewController.view.frame = adminFrame;

self.view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.view.layer.borderWidth = 3;

self.scrollView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
self.scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 5;

contentView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
contentView.layer.borderWidth = 7;


CGRect shareFrame = shareViewController.view.frame;
shareFrame.origin.x = shareFrame.size.width;

[self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"v" : contentView}]];
[self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[v]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"v" : contentView}]];
```

Results: dropbox.com/s/29zwwn6inmdvz0e/Screenshot%202015-08-19%2014.27.47.png?dl=0 , dropbox.com/s/rqsdk9yubq84ph6/Screenshot%202015-08-19%2014.28.14.png?dl=0

Here's an image of the constraints from the storyboard: dropbox.com/s/8c5wkfw81sqd8ij/Screenshot%202015-08-19%2014.28.47.png?dl=0 (pinning edges to superview)

Comment: What _is_ the question? You've described what happens but you haven't said what you think is _wrong_ with that.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was clear - "This only works in the iPhone 5" - how can I change it so that it will work in 4 and 6?

Comment: It is still not at all clear. - Do you understand how autolayout works with scroll views?

Comment: What isn't clear? From the picture and the description, the code above only presents the desired behavior in iphone 5 screens, not in iphone 4 or 6. Clearly I must not understand how auto layout works w/ scroll views if the solution is obvious and I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Well it's hard to say where to start. No one here can see inside your storyboard, but obviously you've done this wrong. For example, you say: "I have a scroll view that's set up inside a storyboard with auto layout constraints so that it fills the entire view". But that is obviously false, since you say (and the picture apparently tries to show) that on an iPhone 6+ the scroll view does _not_ fill the entire view. So you don't even have the basic constraints correct for positioning the scroll view. You can't get the content constraints right until you have the scroll view position right.

Comment: Would it help you to see an example of a scroll view correctly configured using constraints in a storyboard?

Comment: Yeah for sure. I was wrong - I had taken the constraints out of the storyboard, so that image has no constraints. Here's an image w/ constraints set up, note that the views don't extend to the bottom of the page, and there's overlap between the first and second subview. https://www.dropbox.com/s/4prajlefby29165/Screenshot%202015-08-19%2012.38.28.png?dl=0

Comment: (Definitely would be helpful to see appropriate constraints for a 2-subview horizontal scrollview or something analogous)

Comment: (in iPhone 4, meant to show that second subview's height exceeds the window and there's an undesired horizontal scroll) https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojeludv56p8zui0/Screenshot%202015-08-19%2012.41.36.png?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/sirt3j9pi2advex/Screenshot%202015-08-19%2012.40.38.png?dl=0

Comment: I think this example (from my book) is the one you want: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch07p367scrollViewInNibAutolayout2/ch20p673scrollViewInNib You can download it, run it, inspect the storyboard, etc. Notice that there is no code! The scroll view fills the screen, the four rectangles are scrollable inside the scroll view, and all of that is set up completely using constraints.

Comment: Great, will check it out, thank you for the help.

Comment: So, that solution won't work for me - those constraints are the ones that I already have, and I need to load in subviews from nibs, so the size of the scrollview isn't set in the storyboard.

Comment: You don't understand. Nib or code, it's indifferent. You can compose exactly the same constraints in code. So when you load the subviews, that's when you set up the internal constraints. Again, here's an example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p363scrollViewInCode3/ch20p670scrollViewInCode3/ViewController.swift Look at `case 3`, which constructs the entire stack (scroll view, content view, subviews) using constraints.

Comment: Yeah, obviously my point was that I already have those constraints set up in the storyboard and it doesn't work... Those are different constraints in the other example that you showed. I don't doubt that there exists a set of constraints such that this will work, but my frustration comes from the fact that I can't seem to find them. Part of the issue is that the subviews that I'm loading in don't seem to be resizing their heights properly.

Comment: "Part of the issue is that the subviews that I'm loading in don't seem to be resizing their heights properly" They don't resize their heights at all. If you inserting these subviews, sizing and positioning them is completely up to _you_. And of course if you want the scroll view to be scrollable, you must supply sufficient constraints to size the content view from the inside out, as I showed in the second example I pointed you to.

Comment: OK, edited with my edits and the results, still not able to make it function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

bound your scrollview from left,right,top and bottom then it look fine.[image]

and it will look like..

[image]

here is code that i written with yours

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

UIViewController *contentVC = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
contentVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
[self addChildViewController:contentVC];
[self.scrollView addSubview:contentVC.view];
[contentVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:contentVC];

self.view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.view.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
self.scrollView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
self.scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
CGRect adminFrame = contentVC.view.frame;
adminFrame.origin.x = adminFrame.size.width;

UIViewController *shareViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
shareViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self addChildViewController:shareViewController];
[self.scrollView addSubview:shareViewController.view];

shareViewController.view.frame = adminFrame;


CGRect shareFrame = shareViewController.view.frame;
shareFrame.origin.x = shareFrame.size.width;

[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];


// 4) Finally set the size of the scroll view that contains the frames
CGFloat scrollWidth  = 2 * self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat scrollHeight  = self.view.frame.size.height;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is a good solution. These constraints already exist in my storyboard.

Comment: this image code is your code that is running fine after adding these Constraints on my side.

Comment: I really don't think you're running my code - you're missing all of the nibs w/ auto layout constraints.

Comment: yes you are right that, i am not adding your custom viewControllers i am using UIVIewControllers add as ChildViewController.See my edited answer